# tar : the -- 'f' option needs an argument

Tags: civicrm-home

I have created a script that updates civicrm version of the instance I want. This script install with the `wget` command the choosed civicrm version from the civicrm download website. **[https://download.civicrm.org/…](https://download.civicrm.org/%E2%80%A6)**
I use a variable to get the civicrm version and the `tar -xzf` command to extract the zipped folder.

`cms_instance = "drupal"` and `civi_type_version = "p"`

The line with the problem : **tar -xzf $civi_download_prod**
And I got this error in the command line : **tar : the -- 'f' option needs an argument**

**Here is the script :**

```
[ $cms_instance == "drupal" ] && extension="tar.gz"  
[ $civi_type_version == "p" ] && download_link="https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-$civi_version-$cms_instance.$extension" 

if wget -S --spider $download_link  2>&1 | grep 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' > /dev/null 2>&1; 
then
      echo -e '\e[93m=======================================\033[0m'
      echo "The version of CiviCRM you asked is available in the server"
      echo "Instance $cms_instance"
      echo "The actual CiviCRM version is $civi_name"
      echo -e '\e[93m=======================================\033[0m'
      wget $download_link
else
      echo -e '\e[93m=======================================\033[0m'
      echo -e '\e[93m\033[31m No CiviCRM version have been found\033[31m'
      echo -e '\e[93m=======================================\033[0m'
      exit 1
fi

civi="civicrm"
civi_download_prod="$civi-$civi_version-$cms_instance.$extension"

# clear cache civi
cv flush

[ $cms_instance == "drupal" ] && [ $civi_type_version == "p" ] && **tar -xzf $civi_download_prod** && rm -rf $civi_download_prod
```

Command line : **tar : the -- 'f' option needs an argument**

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!

Although this is about downloading CiviCRM files, there is nothing specific to CiviCRM so this might get closed as off-topic.  But we try to be friendly, especially to newcomers :-)

How are you calling the script?  There are a few variables that need to be set.

Maybe try putting `echo "File is $civi_download_prod"` before the last line to confirm the variable is being set correctly.

A few observations on the rest of the script:

- Is this the start of a more comprehensive downloader that will also handle downloads for other CMSes? It seems unnecessarily complex for what it is actually doing.
- I'm not clear what you gain by the first `wget` since you're always downloading it if it exists.  `if wget -q $download_link` would be simpler.
- You don't need `cv flush` before extracting the files.
- It would be preferable to construct the file name once, not twice.

So how about:

```
[ $cms_instance == "drupal" ] && extension="tar.gz"
[ $civi_type_version == "p" ] && download_file="civicrm-$civi_version-$cms_instance.$extension" && download_link="https://download.civicrm.org/$download_file"                                                                                                      

if wget -q $download_link                                                             
then
      echo -e '\e[93m=======================================\033[0m'
      echo "The version of CiviCRM you asked is available in the server"
      echo "Instance $cms_instance"
      echo "The actual CiviCRM version is $civi_name"
      echo -e '\e[93m=======================================\033[0m'
else
      echo -e '\e[93m=======================================\033[0m'
      echo -e '\e[93m\033[31m No CiviCRM version have been found\033[31m'
      echo -e '\e[93m=======================================\033[0m'
      exit 1
fi

[ $cms_instance == "drupal" ] && [ $civi_type_version == "p" ] && tar -xzf $download_file && rm $download_file
```